# interview question related to category and extension

Tags: objective-c, swift

I already failed this interview but hopefully I could learn my mistakes from you guys. the question went like this.

> which of the following can be achieved with 'category' and 'extension'?

```
1. add polymorphism to any existing classes in a platform SDK, e.g. NSString
2. add addition instance variables to existing classes in a platform SKD, e.g.NSString
3. use as a type for declaring variables
4. add additional methods to existing classes in a platform SDK, e.g.NSString
```

In my understanding,

> 

`category` => add more functionality (new method, not property) to class without inheritance, doesn't own the class

> 

`extension` => deals with property, owns class

> 

so then intersection of `category`  and `extension` should be number 3? Did I get it right? someone please shine the light on this.

Comment: Looks like Apple has all the answers: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: 1,4 and partly 2 because it's possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953202/extend-class-in-objective-c-with-variable-based-property/62953444#62953444
in other words !3 because thats out of question. this is what classes are for. if you go along with the idea that an object of a class has a type

Comment: how long was the "test" ?

Comment: thank you for your references! will check it out now.

Comment: 1 hour on system design presentation. 30 ~ 45 mins on these questions. and they gave me 2 hours to finish building some app on the spot.